# AWS RDS: high write IOPS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We are using RDS instance of type `m4.xlarge` in `ap-south-1` region using `Postgres-9.6` Engine.

Yesterday, the write IOPS skyrocketed suddenly. Here are some details around that time. Around 20GB space got filled in 1 and a half hour and then got free automatically. The number of connections also went crazy up to 1500.

Write IOPS Graph,

[image: Write IOPS Graph]

Free Storage Space Graph,

[image: Free Storage Space Graph]

There is no way our application could have written so much data - 20 GB. Even if it had written, how it got automatically deleted?

Is there any way of knowing what happened here? Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: You should check your DB log to get more details of your DB activities. Assume you use postgres as you labeled the question, there could be some background task doing some auto maintenance of your db, like auto-vacuum, that might cause high cpu or iops.

Comment: @WayneWang I checked with AWS support guys. They told us that our queries are making use of temporary tables which is resulting in usage of space and as temporary tables are deleted at the end of the query so space gets cleaned up after immediately.